Почему командная строка не выполняет команды wsl?
Всем здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой что командная строка не выполняет команды wsl. К примеру возьму команду wsl --list --verbose в результате ее выполнения получу следующий вывод :
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

Использование: wsl.exe [Аргумент]

Аргументы:

    --install <Options>
        Установка компонентов подсистемы Windows для Linux. Если параметры не указаны,
        рекомендуемые компоненты будут установлены вместе с дистрибутивом по умолчанию.

        Чтобы просмотреть дистрибутив по умолчанию, а также список других допустимых дистрибутивов,
        используйте "wsl --list --online".

        Параметры:
            --distribution, -d [Аргумент]
                Указывает дистрибутив для скачивания и установки по имени.

                Аргументы:
                    Допустимое имя дистрибутива (без учета регистра).

                Примеры:
                    wsl --install -d Ubuntu
                    wsl --install --distribution Debian

            --inbox
                Установка необязательного компонента Windows вместо версии, доступной в Microsoft Store.

            --enable-wsl1
                Включение поддержки WSL1 в версии Microsoft Store.

            --no-distribution
                Не устанавливать дистрибутив (не может использоваться с параметром --distribution).

            --no-launch, -n
                Не запускать дистрибутив после установки.

            --web-download
                Скачать последнюю версию WSL из Интернета вместо Microsoft Store.

    --list, -l [параметры]
        Перечисление дистрибутивов.

        Параметры:
            --online, -o
                Отображение списка дистрибутивов, доступных для установки с помощью команды "wsl --install".

    --status
        Показать состояние подсистемы Windows для Linux.

    --help
        Вывод сведений об использовании.

Причем неважно какую команду ввожу, по итогу получаю этот результат. С чем это может быть связано? Заранее спасибо.

А откуда вы взяли флаг --verbose? Тут такого нет.

@Alexey Ten флаг --verbose есть в документации майкрософт про wsl. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/basic-commands

А если ее запустить без аргументов, то что происходит?

@avp происходит такой же вывод доступных команд

Я правильно понимаю, что wsl --install -d Ubuntu вы тоже пробовали и также получили только данный вывод?

@avp данную команду не пробовал, так как не очень хоу устанавливать ubuntu на пк. Есть предположение что мне нужно включить в разделе "Включение и отключение компонентов windows" компонент "Подсистема windows для linux". Насколько верно данное предположение и не будет ли у меня при включение пк загружать ubuntu вместо windows?

Не знаю (вообще-то я в линуксе, в винде почти не работаю), но не думаю, что M$ так легко отдастся -)
